# keep image source changed with a function

Tags: javascript, html, function

For a tic tac toe game, I used the following code to change an image source to an 'x' or 'o':

```
var player = 1;    

function changePicture(picture){
        if(player === 1){
            document.getElementById(picture).src = "images/o.png";
            player = 2;
        }
        else if(player === 2){
            document.getElementById(picture).src = "images/x.png";
            player = 1;
        }
    }
```

I would, however, like to keep the x's and o's unchanged if they are clicked afterwards.

Comment: Are you calling `changePicture` from an `onclick` listener and want to disable it after that?

Comment: Can you post the code that attaches the click handler?

Comment: what is 'player' here ? please make it clear !
and when is the function called? Give some more code.

Comment: @Pietu1998: indeed this is the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you approaching this ? 
There are a bunch of ways how to achieve what you need, if you are using `onclick` event you can unset it once you enter this function.

`onclick="changePicture(this);"`

and then :

```
function changePicture(el){
    if(player === 1){
        el.src = "images/o.png";
        player = 2;
    }
    else if(player === 2){
        el.src = "images/x.png";
        player = 1;
    }
    el.onclick ='';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain the state inside each element on the board:

```
function changePicture(picture)
{
    var pic = document.getElementById(picture);

    if (pic._clicked) { return; }

    // mark it
    pic._clicked = player;
    pic.src = (player === 1 ? "images/o.png" : "images/x.png";

    // swap player
    player = 3 - player;
}
```

This uses the `_clicked` property on the picture element; this property shouldn't conflict with any existing properties. It basically marks the picture element with the player that clicked it, so that it won't change and you would later know who was the one clicking it last.